# Is it safe to ignore "Possible missing firmware"?

Tags: kernel, updates

I just got the same error as [Possible missing firmware attempting upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/1366480/80483):

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915                                                                                                      
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
```

and I was wondering if it safe to ignore this (instead of following the advice there).

**PS1**. I just did `apt reinstall linux-firmware` and got the same messages. I suppose that when they disappear, it will be safe to reboot. However, until they do, how do I know that I do not "*have some very specific hardware*" a reboot will not cost me "*something critical like video or wireless*" (quoting comments).

**PS2**. System information:

```
Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Linux version 5.19.0-76051900-generic (jenkins@warp.pop-os.org) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #202207312230~1660780566~22.04~9d60db1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu A
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz  * 8
Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)

lspci  -v -s  $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 158, IOMMU group 1
        Memory at 6022000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: You didn't include a specific filename which was missing, so we don't know if it's a new file to-be-added or the whole linux-firmware package that needs a reinstall.

Comment: @ubfan1: I tracked down the specific messages. I hoped for a generic answer like "it is safe to ignore" ;-)

Comment: It is safe to ignore anyway ;-) It doesn't affect anything unless you have some very specific hardware.

Comment: @Pilot6: how do I know if I "_have some very specific hardware_"?

Comment: What is the GPU in this comp?

Comment: And what is the Ubuntu and kernel version?

Comment: @Pilot6: done; please see PS2

Comment: POPOS and this kernel is off-topic. But it seems your GPU doesn't use these firmware files. I am voting to close the question ass off-topic.

Comment: @Pilot6: what's wrong with PopOS and my kernel?!

Answer (score 1):

It probably could be ignored in most cases, but for me, it causes a very long (like 2-3min) freeze during loading the login screen and after login.

Someone also reported random system freezes here https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/2598

Answer (score 0):

The ....70.1.1 files have not been included in the standard linux-firmware package yet.  "Safe", yes, but likely missing some i915 functionality.  You can wait a bit for the linux-firmware package to be updated, or if you need the missing functionality right away, attempt to download the files from git and install them by copying them into the /lib/firmware/i915 directory.

---

If you wait, the messages will disappear when the linux-firmware package gets updated with a regular update/dist-upgrade. I wouldn't worry about it unless you're missing something critical like video (maybe just hdmi sound) or wireless.

Comment: How will I know that "the linux-firmware package has been updated"?

Comment: I am afraid to reboot because I don't want to lose "_something critical like video or wireless_"

Comment: Don't worry, You wont loose anything by rebooting.